# JSON-Schema: Conditional dependency (by value)

Tags: json, dependencies, jsonschema

This is the simplified JSON-Schema:

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "id": "user",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "account": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "type": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": ["COMPANY", "PERSON"]
                }
            },
            "required": ["type"]
        },
        "person": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "firstName": { "type": "string" },
                "lastName": { "type": "string" }
            },
            "required": ["firstName", "lastName"]
        },
        "company": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "name": { "type": "string" },
                "taxNumber": { "type": "string" }
            }
        }
    },
    "required": ["account", "person"]
}
```

What I want to achieve is:

- If `account.type` is set to `"COMPANY"`:

  - `company` object and its properties should be **required**.
- If `account.type` isset to `"PERSON"`:

  - `company` **object** should be **optional**.
  - But if `company` object is present, `company.name` and `company.taxNumber` should be **required**.

This can be achieved by defining two long sub-schemas under a `oneOf` but that would mean too many duplicates and a complex schema, since `account` and `company` has many more properties than this simplified version.

AFAIK, the only way to define a specific value in a schema is by using the `enum` keyword with a single item. I tried this with the `dependencies` keyword but didn't help.

Can you think of a way without altering the structure of the data object?

Comment: What language are you using? Is it JavaScript?

Comment: JS but language shouldn't matter. This needs to be done within the JSON-schema, not in JS code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can express this requirement using [switch](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/blob/master/KEYWORDS.md#switch-v5-proposal) keyword from JSON-schema v5/6 proposals that is supported in [Ajv](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv) (I am the author).

Comment: I'm already using Ajv, the best validator out there. I'll enable `v5:true` and try `switch` keyword. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to change the schema of a field, depending on the value of another field's value? For example, if "a" is 'TRUE' then "b" must be "FOO" - otherwise "FOO or BOO"

Comment: There's no `switch` keyword by your link anymore.

Answer (score 5):

Under **Draft-07**, you can do it by  conditionally applying schema requirements:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "id": "user",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "account": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "type": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": ["COMPANY", "PERSON"]
                }
            },
            "required": ["type"]
        },
        "person": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "firstName": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "lastName": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": ["firstName", "lastName"]
        },
        "company": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "taxNumber": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "if": {
        "properties": {
            "account": {
                "const": {
                    "type": "COMPANY"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "then": {
        "required": ["account", "person", "company"]
    },
    "else": {
        "required": ["account", "person"]
    }

}
```

Here's a working example that validates against it:

```
{
    "account": {
        "type": "COMPANY"
    },
    "person": {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe"
    },
    "company": {
        "name": "XYZ Corp"
    }
}
```